# Running dependent scheduled queries in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a set of queries I want to run each month in BQ. Let A > B denote that A DEPENDS on B.
I have the below queries:

- q1
- q2 > q1
- q3 > q1
- q4 > q1

As you can see, Queries 2-4 depend on waiting for query 1 to be completed. I really like the ["Scheduled query"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) system in bigquery, but is there anyway that I can leverage it do something like this? The main issue is I cant figure out how to tell my scheduled query to wait until some other query has finished in the BQ console. I know my alternative here is using Google BQ Jobs, but really wanted to see if this was possible to pull off with scheduled query system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run them all as a single script in the scheduled query. Use [BEGIN...EXCEPTION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#beginexception) block:

```
isert into q1_results
select ...
from table;

BEGIN
    isert into q2_results
    select ...
    from q1_results;
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
END;

BEGIN
    isert into q3_results
    select ...
    from q1_results;
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
END;
```

Comment: I was considering this, but my main concern even though q2,q3,q4 are only dependent on q1. As soon as q2 fails, q3 wont even attempt to run. Is that right?

Comment: Oh, sorry. [BEGIN...EXCEPTION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#beginexception) will be a good fit then.

Comment: Hmm I think this might actually be good fit, let me test the functionality and get back to you. Thanks.